# Pure CSS equal height separately nested containers

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

There are plenty of examples of CSS 'equal height columns', 'Holy Grail' layouts, clever implementations of `display: table-cell` and of course some delicious `display: flex` ideas out there, not least here on SO.

But I'm trying to achieve something that I haven't been able to find anywhere else, and I haven't been able to achieve without resorting to JS, which I would rather avoid.

I'm trying to create a set of equal-height parent containers, each of which have a set of child elements which share height between cards. Each card is separated from other the adjacent cards by a gutter. Apparently I can't post images because I'm new, but it's much easier to explain visually. So here's a link to a free image hosting site: http://postimg.org/image/ltcd8ns1l/

In the image, you'll see three cards (1, 2, 3), each of which has three sections (1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3a, 3b, 3c). Each section within a card is the same height as the equivalent section in the other cards (ie. 1b = 2b = 3b, 1c = 2c = 3c, etc). The height of each equivalent section (eg. 1b, 2b & 3b) is determined by the height of the tallest of those sections (ie. the tallest 'b'). The height of the tallest section is determined by the amount of content inside this section.

I have been able to achieve this visually using a `display: table` method, including separate 'table-cell' elements for gutters between cards, but unfortunately the markup is disordered and unsemantic, something like this:

```html
<div class="table-row">
 <div class="heading">heading</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
 <div class="heading">heading</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
 <div class="heading">heading</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
 <div class="body">body text here</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
 <div class="body">body text here</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
 <div class="body">body text here</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
 <div class="foot">footer</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
 <div class="foot">footer</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
 <div class="foot">footer</div>
 <div class="gutter"></div>
</div>
```

...Horrible.

So I was also been able to get something working with `display: flex`. Here is a quick demo in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbXWpQ

And for posterity here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
 <div class="flex-container">
  <a href="#">
   <div class="image">
    <div class="sample-image-one"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="heading">heading: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque 
   </div>
   <div class="body">body text: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa.</div>
   <div class="foot">footer: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis.</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="image">
    <div class="sample-image-two"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="heading">heading: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</div>
   <div class="body">body text: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.</div>
   <div class="foot">footer: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit.</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="image">
    <div class="sample-image-three"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="heading">heading: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error</div>
   <div class="body">body text: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</div>
   <div class="foot">footer: Sed ut perspiciatis.</div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the SCSS:

```scss
// wrap & global styles
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-wrap {
  padding: 3%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  > div {
    margin-right: 3%; 
    width: 25%; // should be 29.33333% but this doesn't seem to work in codepen
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
  }
}

// image sections
.image {
  min-height: 100px;
  order: 1;
  background-color: teal;
  > div {
    background-color: coral;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  &:nth-of-type(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

// sample images of different heights
.sample-image-one { height: 120px; }
.sample-image-two { height: 160px; }
.sample-image-three { height: 80px; }

// copy sections
.heading {
  order: 2;
  background-color: tomato;
  &:nth-of-type(3n+4){
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.body {
  order: 3;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  &:nth-of-type(3n+5){
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.foot {
  order: 4;
  background-color: gold;
  &:nth-of-type(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

I much prefer the HTML using `flex`, as it's in the right order and doesn't contain nonsense elements.

But it doesn't go quite far enough: I want to be able to wrap each card inside its own element, eg. `<article>...</article>`. Partly so the whole card can be a link, but also because to my eye this would provide clearer, more appropriately separated markup. But `flex` doesn't work that way, so it's tricky.

I've fiddled around for ages but I don't see a way to do this without using JS or nasty HTML. Both of which I would prefer to avoid.

Any ideas for how to achieve such a thing?

Comment: not too sure of content, but what if an HTML table wouldn't be the semantic way to structure this content ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't that be the same as my display: table-cell example? The content would still be disordered in the html- header, header, header, body, body, body, footer, footer, footer, etc... Doesn't seem appropriate to the content structure to me.

Comment: if you use html table, then content is semanticly correct , header is related to its content and its footer, with display and div it is broken and is nonsense as you mention : example of my idea (+ css trick onto a link) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBrQLd

Comment: That might just work, thanks! I'll see if I can work an implementation into my project :D

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to have the height the same for `.sample-image-[x]`?

If so, you may want to try setting the container `.image` to `flex-direction: column`, and then using `flex-basis`

```
.image {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height: 100px;
  order: 1;
  background-color: teal;
  > div {
    background-color: coral;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-basis:100px;
  }
  &:nth-of-type(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm actually trying to get all of the variable height contents of each card (ie. image, header, body, footer) to start in the same vertical position, within each card. And I would like the card to be a single element in the HTML. This article describes something very close, but with only one variable height content item per card: http://chriswrightdesign.com/experiments/using-flexbox-today/